# Facebook Login is unable to request instagram_basic permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I follow the [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started) to implement Facebook Login with `instagram_basic` and `pages_show_list`.

`pages_show_list` works. But `instagram_basic` permission keeps failing with the error message.

> Invalid Scopes: instagram_basic. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions%22)

The Instagram account is a business type. I've linked the Instagram account with a Facebook page which I am the admin.

The Facebook Developer account email address is the same as the Facebook account.

This is my code asking permissions

```html
<fb:login-button scope="email, public_profile,pages_show_list,instagram_basic" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
```

I dont know what I am missing here.

Comment: Did you add the product “Instagram Basic Display” in the app dashboard yet?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have Facebook Login and Instagram Basic Display

Comment: Hm, that’s weird. What API version are you initializing the SDK with - maybe a really old one, where this permission did not exist yet? What happens when you try to create an access token for your app in Graph API Explorer, and select the permission there?

Comment: I am using SDK v10.0. In Graph API Explorer, I do not see the 'instagram_basic' permisson. The permission dropdown has 2 categories: User Data Permission and Event Group Page . User Data Permission has email, user_age_range, user_likes etc ... Event Group Page has pages_show_list, user_events, and user_managed_groups.

Comment: Which app “type” did you choose, when you created your app? The different types have access to different features, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/app-types

Comment: I think you hit the pain point. I set the app as "Consumer". Only "Business" type can access to instagram_basic. I can select your answer if you create it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important which app type you choose when setting up your app, different app types have access to different sets of features.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/create-an-app/app-dashboard/app-types

The “Consumer” type should have access to Instagram Basic Display API, according to that list.

`pages_show_list` will require the “Business” type though.